Can't remove h3 in Footer
I am trying to remove this Bewertungen h3 tag but can't find for the live of me where it is.
I have checked: the content/blocks where i can find the list items under it but not the title, The catalog/product itself, the content/page itself, and in the code itself at magento2/app/design/frontend/RVDK/plotservice/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml where it says:
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <container name="kiyoh-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__item-wrapper footer__item-wrapper--dark-blue"
               after="usp-wrapper">
        <container name="row.kiyoh" as="panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__row">
            <container name="footer-copyright" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__copyright"/>
        </container>
    </container>
    <container name="footer-menu-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__item-wrapper footer__item-wrapper--blue"
               after="kiyoh-wrapper">
        <container name="row.footer-menu" as="panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__row">
            <container name="footer-menu" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer__menu">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer-menu-inner"
                       template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/footer-menu.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>

But if I look at the foot-menu.phtml it's empty apart from an empty div:
Does anyone know where the code for this should be or how I could find it?


Check in your admin panel static content blocks. Go to Admin -> Content -> Blocks -> Search for footer links then edit it and edit with page builder and save the content.

Some elements to help you out with that:
Home pages must be linked to a CMS Pages (Ref: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-admin/content-design/elements/pages/page-home-new)

check the name of the cms page for the home page in: store > settings > Configuration > General > Web).

So I would start checking there if the H3 is set in the CMS Pages ( Admin > content > pages )
If it is not there, you can check in Admin > Content > Design > Configuration > Store (and check there in the footer section defined).
Finally, check for values in the DB that duplicate the scope and in the front end, something is being seen that cannot be accessed from the admin.
I hope this quick review is useful and you can complete your task.
